# Unlinkable, grey profile

Tags: discussion, display-names

I ran across a stack overflow [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do) that was written by 'GUIDED BOMB'. The font was completely different than a usual profile. There were no badges or profile picture. Does this mean their account was deleted? What else could it be?

Comment: Yep, deleted account. They may have asked to have their profile deleted, or were kicked off the platform for breaking the rules. In general the reason why a user leaves is not disclosed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. The user account has been deleted.

FWIW, in some cases, when questions are migrated from another sister site and the OP does not have an account in the present site, will also give this kind of appearance, but there will be a note below the question marking the migration, in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Users without a link and reputation are deleted.

For the record, it looks like this:

[image]